# I've got a logical Error in my first if statement program

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, logical-operators

I have typed this code in python,

```
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
if age < 13:
    print("You are a Kid!")
elif (age == 13 and age < 18):
    print("You are a teenager!")
else:
    print("You are an adult!")
```

For the age greater than 13 I'm getting **YOU ARE AN ADULT**
Where did i go wrong? Looking forward for your help :)

Comment: try `age >= 13` instead

Comment: `age >= 13 and age < 18` should be the condition.

Comment: `age == 13 and any_other_test(age)` is only true if `age == 13`, regardless of whatever other test you make. (This is an  application of the law that `False and x == False` regardless the value of `x`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the logic for the else if statement.

`elif(age <= 18)`

Since you already checked if the age is less than 13 you don't need to see if it's equal to or less than, just if it's less than or equal to 18.

Comment: Yeah! Now I got the point and required output as well :) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking between the ages of 13 and 18 instead of simply if they're age is 13 or less than 18.  Python supports chaining logical operators like: `13 <= age < 18`, which I think is quite graceful.

```
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
if age < 13:
    print("You are a Kid!")
elif 13 <= age < 18:
    print("You are a teenager!")
else:
    print("You are an adult!")
```

Comment: Got it :) Thank you!

Comment: @EzhilNC You're welcome! If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.  Have a good one.